# Dúvida sobre chave na criptografia simétrica

Tags: segurança, criptografia

Olá, pesquisando sobre criptografia li sobre criptografia simétrica, assimétrica, assinatura digital...

Mas tenho uma dúvida, quando usamos um software tipo TrueCrypt, KeePass ou outros do gênero a chave da criptografia é a senha que escolhemos? Ou a chave e a senha são coisas distintas?

Se forem coisas diferentes é válido a conclusão de que pouco importa se a criptografia usa chaves de 8 bits ou 4096 bits se a senha for fraca o arquivo criptografado ficará vulnerável?

Essas chaves são arquivos no HD ou outros dispositivos de armazenamento? É possível eu ter acesso direto a elas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma **senha** é algo a ser memorizado pelo usuário, e possivelmente também escolhido pelo usuário. Em geral, as senhas têm baixa [**entropia**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropia_%28teoria_da_informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29), ou seja, embora o número em potencial de candidatos a senha (i.e. todas as strings) seja de muito grande a infinito, as senhas "reais" - aquelas que as pessoas têm a tendência de escolher, ou mesmo pensar - é muito menor. Por essa razão, estima-se que as senhas dos usuários terão uma "segurança" de X bits, e trabalha-se segundo esse pressuposto - ainda que usuários individuais possam escolher senhas mais fortes ou mais fracas.

Uma **chave** é uma sequência de bits usada num procedimento criptográfico. Como cada algoritmo demanda uma chave de tamanho predeterminado, é necessária uma chave com aquele tamanho exato para utilizar naquele algoritmo. Por essa razão, não se pode usar senhas diretamente como chaves, é necessário *transformá-las* segundo um processo qualquer, de modo que a chave resultante tenha o tamanho correto.

Respondendo então à sua primeira pergunta, senha e chave são sim coisas distintas.

O processo que transforma senhas em chaves pode variar bastante, mas uma coisa é certa: se a entrada for a mesma senha, a saída será a mesma chave. Dessa forma, se existem N senhas distintas que podem ser usadas, só existirão *no máximo* N chaves distintas (pode ser menos, pois duas senhas distintas podem derivar a mesma chave). E se dessas N, somente M são senhas "razoáveis" (i.e. que têm alguma chance de serem escolhidas por um usuário), então pode-se esperar que existiram M chaves distintas, pelo menos em 99% dos casos.

Respondendo então à sua segunda pergunta, de fato se a senha for fraca o arquivo fica vulnerável. Cabe notar, entretanto, que usar chaves demasiadamente pequenas (tipo 8 bits) deixa o arquivo vulnerável *até mesmo quando a senha é forte*, enquanto o uso de uma chave maior pelo menos te dá a chance de usar uma senha forte e ter uma proteção razoável. A escolha do tamanho de chave deve portanto se dar pelas características do algoritmo escolhido (ex.: uma chave de 256 bits para ECC tem aproximadamente a mesma segurança de uma chave de 3072 bits para RSA).

Quanto à sua última pergunta, programas como o TrueCrypt e KeePass não armazenam a chave gerada em lugar algum - mesmo porque se seu computador fosse comprometido, o atacante só teria que encontrar o arquivo com a chave para decifrar seus arquivos... Em vez disso, a chave de criptografia é derivada da senha, e isso é feito de novo e de novo cada vez que você quer ganhar acesso ao seu conteúdo. *Enquanto você está usando*, entretanto, a chave fica em memória, sendo descartada somente quando você termina de usar (ex.: você montou um volume TrueCrypt, ele derivou a chave a partir da sua senha, e guardou a chave em memória; você usa esse volume por um certo tempo e, quando decide desmontá-lo, a chave é apagada da memória). Isso *pode ou não* ser um risco, dependendo de como foi implementado (ex.: se o sistema paginou, ou se deu [BSOD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tela_azul_da_morte) e um *core dump* foi parar em arquivo, a chave pode estar presente no seu disco rígido sem você nem se dar conta).

Por fim uma nota sobre o processo de derivação de chaves: sabe-se que as senhas escolhidas pelo usuário normalmente são fracas, e pouco pode se fazer a respeito (a [Lei de Moore](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_de_Moore) diz que os computadores vão ficando mais e mais rápidos com o tempo - permitindo-os testar mais e mais senhas num curto espaço de tempo - mas **nossos cérebros** não ficam melhores para lembrar de senhas mas fortes, de modo que é inevitável que a força relativa das senhas se torne cada vez pior à medida que o tempo passa). Para combater isso, procura-se usar processos de derivação de chave que sejam propositalmente **lentos**, ou seja, que demorem vários segundos (ou mesmo minutos) para gerar a chave a partir da senha mesmo num *hardware* especializado. Isso garante que, mesmo que o número de candidatos a senha a serem testados continue pequeno, o tempo necessário para testar todas elas seja bastante grande. Essa defesa pode não ser o bastante para "salvar" uma senha bastante ruim, mas é considerada suficiente para que senhas "normais" ainda sejam viáveis na prática.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela EXCELENTE resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sou especialista em criptografia, mas leio bastante sobre o assunto e me interesso bastante. Sua pergunta é um pouco ampla e o assunto também. Se falarmos em criptografia existem vários padrões como: [AES](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), [RSA](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA), [OpenPGP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenPGP)... Também existem padrões de Hash de uma via como [MD5](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), [SHA-1](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1), [SHA-2](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), SHA-256...

Mas pegando o exemplo do *[KeePass](http://keepass.info/)* (a qual eu uso). Ele usa o padrão AES, segundo o site oficial:

> KeePass supports the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES, Rijndael) and
> the Twofish algorithm to encrypt its password databases. Both of these
> ciphers are regarded as being very secure. AES e.g. became effective
> as a U.S. Federal government standard and is approved by the National
> Security Agency (NSA) for top secret information.

## O que isso nos diz?

Isso nos diz que o KeePass usa o padrão AES para encriptar a base de senhas e outros campos que você guarda nos arquivos kdbx. Mas se você usa o KeePass, já deve ter reparado que você pode copiar as senhas, certo? Então, elas precisam ser criptografadas e decriptografadas de volta. O AES permite isso.

Com uma chave (acredito que o KeePass que define a chave por padrão e são chaves de 256 bits) ele criptografa e decriptografa a base de dados de senha.

## Sobre Hash

Agora vamos a próxima parte. O KeePass também pede uma senha mestre, o chamado *Master Password*. Sobre esse Master Password o site oficial nos diz:

> SHA-256 is used as password hash. SHA-256 is a 256-bit
> cryptographically secure one-way hash function. Your master password
> is hashed using this algorithm and its output is used as key for the
> encryption algorithms. In contrast to many other hashing algorithms,
> no attacks are known yet against SHA-256.

Aqui já é uma situação mais comum que encontramos por quase toda a internet. Nós definimos uma senha de acesso ao conteúdo, nesse caso o arquivo kdbx. Se a senha estiver correta, acessa, caso contrário, nega o acesso. Porém essa senha não e guardada de forma "texto pleno" pois isso **seria uma falha grave de segurança**. Então é criado um hash da senha usando o algorítmo SHA-256 e então guardado.

Depois de criado o hash, não tem volta. Ou seja, não existe recuperação. Por isso, quando você perde sua senha, a maioria dos sites fazem voce criar uma nova senha. Se o site manda sua senha no e-mail, tenha certeza, aquele site é inseguro.

## Sobre senhas fracas e fortes

A questão de senhas fracas ou fortes é para proteção contra ataques de força bruta, dicionários, raibow tables... Pois fica mais fácil adivinha senhas fáceis.

Veja mais sobre ataques de força bruta **[aqui](http://www.howtogeek.com/166832/brute-force-attacks-explained-how-all-encryption-is-vulnerable/)**.

## Sobre as chaves

Elas são sequências simples de bytes. Se elas são bytes elas podem estar armazenadas em qualquer lugar: HD, Banco de Dados, memória, pendrives... Importa sim se a chave for de 8 bits ou 4096 bits. Quanto maior a chave, mais segurança (o hacker gastará muito mais tempo tentando adivinhar uma chave maior), porém mais tempo de processamento se gastará para encriptar/decriptar uma informação.

## Exemplo prático com Java

Peqguei um exemplo de código Java na web, dei uma adaptada e simplificada. Está funcionando. Ele criptografa e decriptografa uma frase usando AES. De uma olhada. Acho que está fácil de entender.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypt {

    // Chave
    private static byte[] key = { 0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x73, 0x49, 0x73, 0x41,
            0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x79 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String info = "Frase a ser criptografada";
        
        // Criptografa
        byte[] fraseCriptografada = Crypt.encrypt(info);
        
        for(byte b : fraseCriptografada) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        // Decriptografa a Frase
        String fraseDecript = Crypt.decrypt(fraseCriptografada);
        System.out.println(fraseDecript);

    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        byte[] encryptedString = null;
        
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            encryptedString = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;

    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] byteToDecrypt) {
        String decryptedString = null;
        
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            decryptedString = new String(cipher.doFinal(byteToDecrypt));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        
        return decryptedString;
    }
}
```

Saída do console do exemplo acima:

```
-82-704594-7111794-17-59262-52-9734-27110-1143353-74-8794-8710211643-16-1111178741103
Frase a ser criptografada
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Entendi que é criado um hash de 256bits com a Master Password e esse hash é usado com chave para o algoritmo AES256. Mas essa chave (o resultado do hash) fica armazenada em algum lugar ou é gerada cada vez que se insere a Master Password? Pq se ficar armazenada seria uma falha de segurança certo?

Comment: bigown Vi oq vc escreveu, pode apagar se quiser...

Comment: @YuriCastilhoWermelinger, não acredito que a senha (hash) seja usada como chave para a criptografia. Agora, se a chave AES é gerada a cada vez que se abr o kdbx e fecha e recriptografa tudo, é só olhando no código dele mesmo e ver como ele trabalha. Mas isso seria possível sim.

Comment: Eu entendi que o hash é a chave da criptografia pois na sua resposta há uma menção a um texto do site oficial que diz "Your master password is hashed using this algorithm and its output is used as key for the encryption algorithms."

Comment: @YuriCastilhoWermelinger, você está correto. O KeePass utiliza o hash do Master Password como chave do AES. Pesquisei mais um pouco e confirmei.  
  
"In order to generate the 256-bit key for the block ciphers, the Secure Hash Algorithm SHA-256 is used. This algorithm compresses the user key provided by the user (consisting of password and/or key file) to a fixed-size key of 256 bits. This transformation is one-way, i.e. it is computationally infeasible to invert the hash function or find a second message that compresses to the same hash." http://keepass.info/help/base/security.html